# Adverb or adjective?

Tags: parts-of-speech, parallelism

In this sentence, is "declining" an adverb? Gerund (noun that uses a verb + ing form)? Or adjective?

> The university's board of trustees, being worried over declining
>   student enrollments and their failing to secure additional funding
>   from the state, has formed a committee to determine what cuts need to
>   be made to staff and programs.

Is there a parallelism error here between "declining student enrollments" and "their failing to secure...". How would you fix it?

Comment: Do the test. You think it's an adverb? Replace it with another adverb. You think it's an adjective? Replace it with an adjective. "Being worried over slow/gorgeous/orange enrollments"? Ayup. "Being worried over slowly/beautifully/colorfully enrollments"? You don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjective.

"over declining student enrollments" is a prepositional phrase. Declining and students are both adjectives which describe enrollments.

Failing is being used as a noun (gerund), but it is very awkward. It would be better to use the word failure instead.

Also, personally, I would remove the word being.

Comment: Is there a parallelism problem?

Comment: Also what kind of adjective is "declining"? Also what is "to secure"? Why do we use the "to" + infinitive here?

Comment: I agree with @Mark about changing the wording from "failing to secure..." to "failure to secure...".  I don't feel there is a parallelism problem.

Comment: I don't see a parallelism problem either. I assume there is some kind of name for an adjective like declining, but I don't know what that name would be. The infinitive "to secure", in this case begins an infinitive phrase "to secure additional funding".

Comment: Mark is right. Specifically, it's a participle - a word based on a verb, used as an adjective.

Comment: Participles are verbs. They're often **used** as adjectives (or adverbs, or conjunctions, or prepositions, or complementizers), but they're still verbs, because they can form clauses with subjects and direct objects.